# Can a struct have contract instance?

Tags: solidity, struct

I have been using structs like:

```
contract gas {

    struct example { 
       uint256 num;
       string name;    
      }

}
```

I want to use an instance of other Contract in struct like:

```
contract token {

   struct example2 {
     gas g1; //instance of gas
     uint256 num;
     ...
     }

}
```

Is it possible to use contract gas' g1 instance in struct of contract token (and later instantiate it when instantiating the example2 struct)? disclaimer: Im new in solidity (like 3 days new) so go easy! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. See this example

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.20;

contract ContractA {
    uint num;

    function ContractA(uint n) public {
        num = n;
    }

    function get() public view returns(uint) {
        return num;
    }
}

contract ContractB {

    struct Info {
        ContractA ainstance;
    }
    mapping(uint => Info) infoMapping;
    uint length;

    function ContractB() public {

    }

    function create(uint n) public {
        infoMapping[length] = Info(
            new ContractA(n)
        );
        length++;
    }

    function get(uint index) public view returns(uint) {
        return infoMapping[index].ainstance.get();
    }

}
```

the contract instance is just an address, so it can be save either explicitly or saving the address and cast it later. A revert exception will be thrown in case you're trying to perform operation that are not allowed in the contract (eg not existing methods)

Comment: Perfect. Also it should be more expensive to create this struct since it acquires  more storage space?

Comment: you're saving the contract instance (address) with is 20 bytes. You can see the instance also as `address ainstance`

Comment: so every time "new ContractA(n)" is called a new address is assigned? I thought it would create storage on blockchain for the instance and not assign a new address? (much like java classes instance stored in heap memory )

Comment: yes, you create new storage on the blockchain with the data you save in the linked contract. I meant, in the original one, you would have only a reference.

Comment: can we also do : mapping(uint => ContractA) infoMapping ?

Comment: yes, no issue with that. Either `mapping(uint => ContractA)` or `mapping(uint => address)` are fine (in the second case you need to cast the address to use the contract)